# Função que retorna outras funções

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Tenho três métodos sendo chamados separadamente no *controller* com JSON. Cada uma delas me retorna **`Id Name`**.

Preciso chamar esses três métodos numa mesma função no *controller*. Como posso juntar os três métodos na mesma função?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetMessageClassByResourceByDevice(int resourceId, string deviceName)
{                
    return  Json(EventFlow.GetMessageClassByResourceByDevice(resourceId, deviceName)
        .Select(f => new { EventMessageClassId = f.Id, FullName = f.Name }));

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetMessageGroupByResourceByDevice(int resourceId, string deviceName)
{
    return Json(EventFlow.GetMessageGroupByResourceByDevice(resourceId, deviceName)
        .Select(f => new { EventMessageGroupId = f.Id, FullName = f.Name }));

}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetMessageByResourceByDevice(int resourceId, string deviceName)
{
    return Json(EventFlow.GetMessageByResourceByDevice(resourceId, deviceName)
        .Select(f => new { EventMessageId = f.Id, FullName = f.Name }));
}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem o que deseja, mas parece que não dá para melhorar muito mais que isso. Eu acho, mas posso estar errado que está querendo fazer DRY onde não cabe. Veja isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101 Mas se explicar melhor, posso tentar ver se algo pode ser feito.

Comment: Cada *Action* retorna um `JsonResult` diferente. Qual a ideia? Juntar todos os JSON em um só?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer retornar a lista do conteúdo dos três retornos dos métodos, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetMessageClass(int resourceId, string deviceName)
{
  var list = new List<dynamic>();

  list.Add((dynamic)GetMessageClassByResourceByDevice(resourceId, deviceName).Data);
  list.Add((dynamic)GetMessageGroupByResourceByDevice(resourceId, deviceName).Data);
  list.Add((dynamic)GetMessageByResourceByDevice(resourceId, deviceName).Data);

  return Json(list);
}
```

Se você quiser retornar o primeiro dos retornos não nulos, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetMessageClass(int resourceId, string deviceName)
{
  var ret = (dynamic)GetMessageClassByResourceByDevice(resourceId, deviceName).Data;
  if (ret != null) {
    ret = (dynamic)GetMessageGroupByResourceByDevice(resourceId, deviceName).Data;
  }
  else if (ret != null) {
    ret = (dynamic)GetMessageByResourceByDevice(resourceId, deviceName).Data;
  }

  return Json(ret);
}
```